Acer Aspire A114-33 Ubuntu Studio 24.04LTS wifi not detected
I've followed the instructions in this answer to no effect:
Acer Aspire 5 a515-56-77SX Ubuntu 21.04 wifi not detected

I have disabled secureboot

Here is my info:
$ uname -a Linux vashti-Aspire-A114-33 6.8.0-47-lowlatency
#47.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct  7 15:01:17 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

And here is some more:
$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for vashti: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 15
       serial: 74:d4:dd:5a:8c:38
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-47-lowlatency duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=10.0.0.27 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:7f904000-7f904fff memory:7f900000-7f903fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff memory:6001000000-60010fffff memory:7f800000-7f807fff

And my rfkill info:
$ sudo rfkill list all
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no


You do mention the low latency kernel being used; do you still have the problem when low latency isn't used? as Ubuntu Studio & docs do highlight some issues with low latency kernel, thus the recommendation not to use it unless its absolutely required.

Please edit the question to include results from terminal for lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net
